# Finding the children of each and every node while traversing upto the leaves of the tree using Gremlin

Tags: java, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

Suppose i have a tree like [image]

Now staring at vertex `8`, I want to find the children of vertex `8` ie {3,10},Store them in a **map** and again continue the same procedure for the remaining vertices until i reach the leaf nodes(the height of the tree  is unknown while writing the query).

I want to write a query which will perform the above operations and should return an **Iterator** containing these **maps**.
Please help me in writing this query.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider [tree](http://gremlindocs.com/#side-effect/tree) step:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> t=new Tree();g.v(1).out.tree(t).loop(2){true}
gremlin> t
==>v[1]={v[2]={}, v[3]={}, v[4]={}}
==>v[4]={v[3]={}, v[5]={}}
```

I didn't fully follow the expected format portion of your question, so I'm not sure if the above accomplishes exactly what you asked for.  You could likely use some groovy to convert `t` from there as needed as it gets most of the work done out-of-the-box.

Comment: Hi @stephen, the query works  perfectly. One small doubt. My query is like  `g.V().has("mgrNo",814754).out.tree(t).loop(2){true}` and the corresponding output is                                                           `v[4156928] = {v[24320]={}, v[8156672]={}}`
`v[7980032] = {v[4156928]={}}`
`v[24320] = {v[92160]={}, v[8165376]={}}`
`v[8156672] = {v[92160]={}, v[8165376]={}}`. According to the query , mgrNo corresponds to v[7980032]. But it is returning as the second entry in tree instead of first.

Comment: There aren't guarantees on order of a `Tree` as it is based on `HashMap`: https://github.com/tinkerpop/pipes/blob/57e9f796fee807badea79c7cbe1ed004bd659c79/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/pipes/util/structures/Tree.java

Comment: If the query has cycles then this query will loop infinitely right?

Comment: yes - i tend not to like to write `.loop(2){true}` - a sensible default for stopping the loop like `loop(2){it.loops<1024}` is usually considered better practice.  i think i had assumed that you didn't have cycles when i answered this.

Comment: Is there any way to get the vertices in the same order we are traversing though the tree.Since the `tree` is not guaranteed for the order

Comment: TinkerPop does not contractually enforce order on graphs as most graphs do not support it.  If you are specifically asking about "traverse order" then I think you might need to write your own tree pipe: https://github.com/tinkerpop/pipes/blob/57e9f796fee807badea79c7cbe1ed004bd659c79/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/pipes/sideeffect/TreePipe.java

Answer (score 0):

To perform the same query in GremlinPipeLine

```
Tree tree = new Tree();
    new GremlinPipeline(graph).V().has("mgrNo", 814754).out("manager of").tree(tree).loop(2, new PipeFunction<LoopBundle,Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean compute(LoopBundle loopBundle) {
            return true;
        }
    }).iterate();
Iterator it = tree.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());

       }
    }
```